# Ice Cream Sandwich Style Tabs

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-tabs

Does anyone know of a **tutorial/example** for `Ice Cream Sandwich` style tabs (with swipe left/right - like in the `YouTube` app) that *isn't* for the backward compatibility support library. Just need API level 14 or 15.

My project only has to work on `Ice Cream Sandwich` on my `Galaxy Nexus`. So I'd like to know how this is done without needing backward compatibility.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: [This](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) will help you Happy Coding

Comment: It's a library to solve your problem. Developed and distributed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. Originally based on widgets developed by Patrik Åkerfeldt. Similar to the title indicator but displays as many titles as possible in scrolling and animated horizontal tabs.

Comment: Given that my reason for wanting to do this "without backwards compatibility" was because I thought it'd be simpler. I've actually ended up using this as it is the easiest option and gives you backwards compatibility for free.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's not really a reason to specifically avoid backwards compatibility, since if you don't want older devices using it, you can specify the minimum API version in the manifest for your app.

That said, the [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) is the way that Google does it, and it leverages `Fragments`, which while they are backwards compatible, are built into Android 4.

If you don't care to use `Fragments` but just want to swipe from `View` to `View`, you can use a regular `PagerAdapter` with it instead of a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, or you could use a [`ViewFlow`](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow).

The example on the ViewFlow page is for support v4, but there are also some examples [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support13Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv13/app/index.html) for API 13+ which may be closer to what you're looking for ([this one](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support13Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv13/app/FragmentPagerSupport.html) in particular).

Comment: I think my line of thinking was that it'd probably be a lot simpler and less code. I may be wrong there...

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only thing in the code example on the `ViewPager` page that's done explicitly for compatibility purposes is the one class it gets from `FragmentPagerSupport`.  Everything else is pretty standard boilerplate: create your `Activity`, give it a tab bar, an `Adapter`, and a set of `Views` (or `Fragments`) for that Adapter to display.

Comment: Although the actual example they give is more complicated because it uses Action Bar tabs in particular--I don't know whether you want to do that or not but it does have a nice ICS look-'n'-feel to it.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have achieved an [ActionBar with "tabs+swipe" navigation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#considerations-split-action-bars) on your API 14+ device. the whole thing can be adapted to pre-Honeycomb devices, since I just happened to have made a demo for that myself.

The most easy way is, basically, you just have to:

- extend/import **com.actionbarsherlock** classes whevever possible!
- import from **android.support.v4** (instead from the usual **android**) package, wherever possible!

However, before you can do those, you would have to have to first:

- known how to use the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html), seemingly a.k.a. the Compatibility Library.
- know how to get started using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html).

For example (MainActivity.java):

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {/*...*/}
```

Comment: Down voted because this is the exact opposite of what was asked.  Presumably, the reason to void backwards compatibility is to avoid learning and/or depending on external libraries.

Comment: As I have remembered from the time I answered the question, the question had not been worded that way. Considering how the question is worded now, my answer should indeed be voted down. Quite unfortunate for a new guy like me I would say. Laughs.